# C#, Winforms, .manifest: Как определить Scale?

Tags: c#, windows, .net, winforms, windows-10

Уважаемые господа,

я пытаюсь в приложении (C#, .NET Framework 4.8 под Windows 10) определить параметр Scale - показан на картинке.

[image: scale]

Предыстория вопроса: хочу заставить приложение работать одинаково, несмотря на то, как у пользователя установлен этот параметр.

После многих экспериментов я понял, что единственный способ написать такое приложение - сделать, чтобы независимо от Scale у меня всегда рисовалось окно из одного и того же числа точек на экране.

То есть, фактически, я хочу сам управлять тем, как у меня будет отрисовано окно приложения.

Прописав приложению так называемый manifest-файл, точнее, добавив в него такую секцию:

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">True/PM</dpiAware>
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2,PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
      <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

я добился того, что окно приложения, независимо от установок Scale, рисуется - в точках - одинакового размера.

Но при этом изменяются размеры шрифта, которым сделаны надписи в форме, пример на следующих двух картинках, соответсвующих `scale=100%` и `scale=125%`:

[image: 100%]

[image: 125%]

Я попробовал определить установленный scale (для того, чтобы "вручную" подправить размер шрифта), и убедится, что первые несколько примеров, найденных на SO, не работают, всегда выдавая мне результат "у тебя установлен Scale 100%".

Что я пробовал:

1. наивный способ [отсюда](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/402933/how-to-detect-the-windows-10-scale-factor-using-c.html)
2. чуть более замороченный способ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/)
3. способ, который ну должен уже работать, суда по фундаментальности подхода, [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60872044/)

Сам проект, который можно загрузить и запустить, лежит [здесь](https://github.com/junecat/ScalePrj1) (гитхаб)

Код из примеров вставлен прямо в `Program.cs`, и вызывается из единственной формы в событии `Shown`.

**Нельзя ли навести меня на правильный способ определения scale в таком приложении?**

Спасибо большое!

Comment: Запустил ваш проект на Winforms под .NET 6, получил из `this.DeviceDpi` значение 192, что соответствует масштабированию 200% моего 4к дисплея (96x2), при этом данный метод всегда возвращал 96 на старом фреймворке. То есть обозначенной проблемы, как я и сказал, в .NET 6 нет. Хотя в некоторых моментах придется все равно какие-то гайки подкрутить, чтобы все стало универстально и красиво.

Comment: @aepot - Большое спасибо!
правильно ли я понимаю, что "лечить" проект на NET Framework 4.8 - бесперспективно? То есть, я попробовал - в FW 4.8 this.DeviceDpi=96. А в NET 6.0 - да, там у меня 125% и this.DeviceDpi=120, всё ОК. И еще одно уточнение: вы при конвертации *.manifest - файл оставили?

Comment: нет, для .NET 6 манифест не нужен, там DPI Awareness включено по умолчанию

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/3832#issuecomment-689105038

Comment: Не забывайте про событие DpiChanged, юзер может сменить DPI когда захочет, а так же у него может быть 2 монитора с разным DPI

Comment: Возможно, это вам поможет это решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248457